# Calculating ratio only gives 0 or 1?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a section of T-SQL code that looks something like this:

```
select @automation_rate = 
  case 
    when @total_count = 0 then 0
    else @automated_count / @total_count
  end
```

@automation_rate is decimal(3,2). @total_count and @automated_count are integers.

Unfortunately the only values ever returned for @automation_rate are either 0 or 1. Clearly there is something wrong here, and it may be ridiculously simple, but for the life of me I can't see it.

All data in the underlying resultset (I'm looping over a table) is either 0 or a positive integer. All values are integers except for the automation rate.

Here's example values and expected (using a calculator) vs actual results:

```
automated count     total count     expected ratio     actual ratio
---------------     -----------     --------------     ------------
              0              35                0.0             0.00
             98             258              37.98             0.00
             74             557              13.29             0.00
            140             140               1.00             1.00
```

As you can see I get a ratio of 0.00 for all values except where automated = total. I also have an Excel spreadsheet that does the same basic calculation and it comes out perfect (i.e. just like the "expected" column) every time.

So where did I go wrong?

*(This is on MS SQL Server 2005, on the off chance that has any impact at all)*

**Edit** Thanks to everyone for the answers. I blew the integer rounding part by assuming since it was moving into a decimal data type that it would automatically convert, instead of realizing it would do the calculation, round, and *then* convert. Everyone had similar answers so upvotes all around.

Comment: Your expected ratio isn't 37.98 it's 0.3798, i.e. it's less than 0.5 i.e. it's 0. What is the data type of `automated_count` and `total_count`, are they floats?

Comment: No they are ints. You are correct and I was inaccurate in my representation above. I was using a calculator to run the numbers and in a hurry typed them in as 37.98 instead of 0.3798 etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to be due to integer math, since @automated_count and @total_count are obviously integers. You need to say:

```
1.0*@automated_count / @total_count
```

Or more explicitly:

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2), @automated_count) / @total_count
```

Also these will yield 0.3798 etc. so you might want:

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2), 100.0*@automated_count / @total_count)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. Wasn't aware of the rounding issue, I thought since it was going into a decimal data type it would automatically convert. I prefer being explicit in code so your solution wins.

Answer (score 4):

Since both values used on your division are integers, then it returns an integer. You need to cast one of them to decimal for this to work:

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2),@automated_count) / @total_count
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Don't worry, I rejected the edit. In any case, you are right, `DECIMAL(3,2)` wasn't a good choice. I upvoted your answer since is far more complete than mine

Answer (score 2):

When you do math with integers, SQL Server rounds.

Try:

```
    select @automation_rate =
    case
      when @total_count = 0 then 0.00
     else (@automated_count * 1.00) / @total_count
   end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are truncating. Anything dealing with all ints and no doubles will alwalys truncate into an int. 0.x will end up being 0.